# Want to show dependent popup thru javascript, that also work in IE7 and above

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to show a popup window by javascript function, with folloing conditions-
-Popup should be in Center of page.
-User can not be able to access parent page when popup opened.
-also work in IE7 or above.

However I am trying with followng code but did not got success.

```
 window.open('PopUp.aspx', 'popjack',
        'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no,scrollbars=no,width=955,height=500');
```

can it would easy by jQuery?
Thanks in advanced.!

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery UI [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Basic modal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>

<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Dialog should now open to the center of the window and it should be modal (user cannot interact with other elements than the dialog).